# Trouble extracting First and LastName from Full Name column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am having `FullName` column and I am extracting the `First Name` and `last name` using the following query

```
select  SUBSTRING(FULL_NAME, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', FULL_NAME) - 1) AS FirstName,
        SUBSTRING(FULL_NAME, CHARINDEX(' ', FULL_NAME) + 1, 500) AS LastName
from [dbo].[TABLE]
```

But in the `Full Name` column there are just First names, some 10 digit phone numbers, 4 digit extensions and some text like '*this is a special case*'.

How should I modify my query to accommodate these exceptions? And also when there are only single words in the Full Name column I am getting this following error message:

> "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."

Comment: sounds like a job for a function to me

Comment: Sounds like you need to rethink that table to me. Why are there non names in there?

Comment: Did you do a bulk import and misjudge the field separators?  In any case, try to have a standard first_name column, a standard sur_name column, and a computed full_name column instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing good names from free form fields is not an easy task...

I would suggest a dual approach.

Identify common patterns, i.e.   you might find phone number with something like this

```
Where IsNumeric( Replace(Field,'-','')=1
```

and you might identify single names with

```
Where charindex(' ',trim(field))=0
```

etc.

Once you've identified them, the write code to attempt to split them...

So you might use the code you have above with the following WHERE clause

```
  select SUBSTRING(FULL_NAME, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', FULL_NAME) - 1) AS FirstName,
         SUBSTRING(PRQ_BP_CONTACT_NAME, CHARINDEX(' ', FULL_NAME) + 1, 500) 
         AS LastN
  from [dbo].[TABLE]
  where charindex(' ',trim(field))>0 and Where IsNumeric( Replace(Field,'-','')=0
```

Use the WHERE clauses to **(a)** make sure you only get records you can parse and **(b)** help identify the oddball cases you'll like need to do by hand...

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You could go with a function this allows you to put in any logic you need in the transform and keep things a bit more readable :

```
create function dbo.namepart( @fullname varchar(50), @part varchar(5)) 
returns varchar(10)
as 
begin 
  declare @first varchar(50)
  declare @last varchar(50)
  declare @sp int
  if @fullname like '%special value%' return ''
  if @fullname like '% %'
  begin
    set @sp = CHARINDEX(' ', @fullname) 
    set @first = left(@fullname, @sp  - 1)
    set @last = substring(@fullname,@sp + 1 ,50)
    if isnumeric(@last) <> 0  set @last = ''
  end 
  else 
  begin
    set @first = @fullname 
    set @last = '' 
  end 
  if @part like 'f%' 
    return @first
  else 
    return @last
  return ''
end
```

Sample data

```
create table blah(
  full_name varchar(50)
)

insert into blah values ( 'john smith' ), ('paul 12345'),('evan'),('special value')
```

And see if it works

```
select 
  dbo.namepart(full_name,'first') first, 
  dbo.namepart(full_name,'last') last,
  full_name
from blah
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eb28f/2